# Android Espresso shards randomly fail with INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK

Tags: android, integration-testing, android-espresso, android-testing, androidx

EDIT: Below is the original post. It was the initial issue I had ran into, but repeating my steps over and over I am getting different results. The first time I tried to run my shards after posting this, I got:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':ProgressiveApp:packageInternalStaging'.
> invalid distance too far back
```

The next time:

```
> invalid code lengths set
```

And the next:

```
> Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream
```

All three appear to be zip/compression related issues. Perhaps this is my primary issue.

Original post below:

---

I'm using AndroidX Espresso 3.1.0 along with ANDROIDX_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR. The only issue I have is that when I run shards (to speed up test runs), it sometimes decides to fail for no good reason.

For example, I open three terminals and three emulators. I run one of these in each terminal to kick off three separate shards:

```
ANDROID_SERIAL=emulator-5554 ./gradlew connectedAndroidTest -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.numShards=3 -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.shardIndex=0
ANDROID_SERIAL=emulator-5556 ./gradlew connectedAndroidTest -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.numShards=3 -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.shardIndex=1
ANDROID_SERIAL=emulator-5558 ./gradlew connectedAndroidTest -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.numShards=3 -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.shardIndex=2
```

This then runs a third of my tests on each emulator. So good so far. After a long time, they're all done and I have a nice HTML report telling me zero tests failed. I haven't touched my code, I haven't touched the emulators. I go to touch each of the terminals. In each I hit the up arrow to grab the last command ran in that terminal, and then enter to rerun exactly what I just ran. Two of the emulators are fine and run through all their tests. The third does not, and gives me this error message below:

```
> Task :<snip>:connectedInternalStagingAndroidTest FAILED
[no message defined]
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: 
com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1431)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
Caused by: com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK
    at com.android.builder.testing.ConnectedDevice.installPackage(ConnectedDevice.java:132)
    at com.android.builder.internal.testing.SimpleTestCallable.call(SimpleTestCallable.java:147)
    at com.android.builder.internal.testing.SimpleTestCallable.call(SimpleTestCallable.java:59)
    at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1424)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK
    at com.android.ddmlib.Device.installRemotePackage(Device.java:1031)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Device.installPackage(Device.java:902)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Device.installPackage(Device.java:880)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Device.installPackage(Device.java:869)
    at com.android.builder.testing.ConnectedDevice.installPackage(ConnectedDevice.java:126)
    ... 7 more
```

Why? How? It doesn't make any sense. I hit up and enter again and then it happily runs through all the tests without issue.

My problem is that this random failure happens enough I can't set up my machines to use sharding, and therefore cannot speed up the test running process for my team.